# Add raster layer or a WMS using geotools - problem to run the jar file from cmd

Tags: raster, wms, geotools

I am using geotools in order to develop a custom GIS.

I tried to add a raster layer and a WMS based on the tutorials given by geotools. When i am running the project using the main class in Netbeans or Eclipse everything is working properly. However, when i tried to run the jar file from the cmd, the above functionalities crashes. Below you can see a screenshot which shows the error regarding the WMS.

I forgot to send that the project which i am working on is a Maven project.

Can you help me to understand where is the problem?

[image]

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>13.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>13.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>13.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xsd-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-xsd-kml</artifactId>
        <version>9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.geotools.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>gt-jdbc-postgis</artifactId>
          <version>13.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1103-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you add your maven pom file - or a dependancy list. It looks like a missing jar

Comment: I add the list of dependencies in the question below, Thanks a lot

Comment: and how did you build the jar you are running at the command line?

Comment: I build the project using netbeans and then i am trying to run the jar which is located in the "target folder" from the command line. (java -jar nameJar.jar)

Comment: I also tried to build the project from cmd, however the problem is the same

Comment: try mvn exec:java - though I don't know if your pom file is configured for that

Comment: I tried to do what you suggest, but maybe the pom.xml is not configured for this. I have quite the same problem when i am trying to make a connection with postgresql...it seems that the declared dependencies are not included correctly to the jar file..Is it possible?

Comment: that really depends on whether you told netbeans to include the jars - see http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app

Comment: hmm...i do not know, i am gonna check it and i will be back..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is answered in the [GeoTools FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app) - basically you need to combine all the required dependency jars into your executable jar so that users don't need to worry about the classpath. Normally this is pretty easy to achieve using the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) in maven, however when using GeoTools' datastores (and other factories) this will fail as only the last found `SPI` file in `META-INF/services` will be saved.

So you need to use the maven [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) to combine the services files into a single larger file that will work in the combined jar.

You need to add a block like the following to your maven pom file:

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                          <!-- This bit sets the main class for the executable jar as you otherwise -->
                          <!-- would with the assembly plugin                                       -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <manifestEntries>
                                  <Main-Class>org.geotools.demo.Quickstart</Main-Class>
                              </manifestEntries>
                          </transformer>
                          <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files         -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                      </transformers>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
```

You'll need to change the main class name to match your program of course, and then run `mvn package:shade` to create the new jar.